# line_items_path(:product_id => product) -- What does this line do ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I saw this code in agile rails development code

```
line_items_path(:product_id => product)
```

and is not able to figure out how it is working. I can see it is used for adding products to cart but how does this _path function works here ?

Comment: you will have to give use the definition of the function if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find where **line_item_path** point to in **config/route.rb**
**:product_id** it's a params then you can read at function specified from **line_item_path**